# Android Studio 4.2.1 NullPointer Exception on startup

Tags: java, android, android-studio, nullpointerexception

I wanted to continue working on my app with Android Studio today, but when I want to start Android Studio, I currently get the error that can be seen below every time. I haven't changed anything on my system, nor have I made a Java update.

I would be delighted to receive quick help

greetings, Alex

```
Internal error. Please refer to https://code.google.com/p/android/issues

java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTextUI$RootView.paint(BasicTextUI.java:1524)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTextUI.paintSafely(BasicTextUI.java:753)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTextUI.paint(BasicTextUI.java:911)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTextUI.update(BasicTextUI.java:890)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.paintComponent(JComponent.java:800)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1077)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.paintToOffscreen(JComponent.java:5263)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paintDoubleBufferedImpl(RepaintManager.java:1654)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paintDoubleBuffered(RepaintManager.java:1629)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paint(RepaintManager.java:1566)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.RepaintManager.paint(RepaintManager.java:1333)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent._paintImmediately(JComponent.java:5211)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.paintImmediately(JComponent.java:5021)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.RepaintManager$4.run(RepaintManager.java:868)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.RepaintManager$4.run(RepaintManager.java:851)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:851)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:826)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.RepaintManager.prePaintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:775)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.RepaintManager$ProcessingRunnable.run(RepaintManager.java:1901)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:313)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:776)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:727)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:721)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:746)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:419)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:117)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$2.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:190)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:313)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:776)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:727)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:721)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:746)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:419)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)

-----
JRE 11.0.8+10-b944.6842174 amd64 by N/A
C:\Users\alwe9\AppData\Local\JetBrains\Toolbox\apps\AndroidStudio\ch-0\202.7351085\jre
```

Comment: Information that would help would include operating system and version, but you might also want to consider [filing a bug](https://developer.android.com/studio/report-bugs) with the Studio team (with the info on that page).

Comment: I don't think this issue is something that can be fixed here on Stack Overflow (as the above issue is more of an IDE technical support question). I can however offer some advice for people who encounter the same issue (knowing that I myself encounter this from time to time), you may simply use the **built-in report** feature of the IDE (and I believe people should be able to find the feature available on every error like this), and let the Android Studio IDE maintainers fix the problem on their next update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i could fixed this issue. it fixed by it self with a restart on the next day

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was a firewall problem. I know you stated that nothing on your computer had changed, but I wanted to put this here just in case it gives someone a clue.